# Show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^{\pi/2} 2^n \sqrt{n} \sin^n(x) \cos^{n-2}(x) \; dx = \sqrt{2\pi}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, definite-integrals

I wish to show
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^{\pi/2} 2^n \sqrt{n} \sin^n(x) \cos^{n-2}(x) \; dx = \sqrt{2\pi}$$

I've tried substitution and integration by parts to get a recursive formula for the integral, but so far it hasn't worked. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Use $\sin^n x = (\sin^{n-2}x)(\sin^2 x) = (\sin^{n-2}x)(1-\cos^2 x)$.  Then use parts to end up with $\sin^{n-2}x \cos^{n-2}x$ which you collapse to a single trig function via the double angle formula for sine.  See the 16th line here ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_trigonometric_functions#Integrands_involving_both_sine_and_cosine ) for help on the parts step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will present you the main steps to a final solution and the details on each step can be your job.

First notice that a simple substiution $n=2k$ gives

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^{\pi/2} 2^n \sqrt{n} \sin^n(x) \cos^{n-2}(x) \; dx = \lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^{\pi/2} 2^{2k} \sqrt{2k} \sin^{2k}(x) \cos^{2k-2}(x) \; dx$$ 
Now elaborating with the new expression in the following way we have

$$2^{2k-1} \sqrt{2k}\cdot2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2(k+1/2)-1}(x) \cos^{2(k-1/2)-1}(x) \; dx$$

\begin{eqnarray}
&=& 2^{2k-1}\sqrt{2k}\cdot\beta(k+1/2,k-1/2) \\ 
&=& 2^{2k-1}\sqrt{2k}\frac{\Gamma(k+1/2)\Gamma(k-1/2)}{\Gamma(2k)} \\ 
&=& 2^{2k}\sqrt{2k}\frac{2k}{2k-1}\cdot\frac{\Gamma(k+1/2)^2}{\Gamma(2k+1)} \\ 
&=& 2^{2k}\sqrt{2k}\frac{2k}{2k-1}\cdot\frac{(\frac{(2k-1)!!\sqrt{\pi}}{2^{k}})^{2}}{(2k)!} \\
&=& \pi\cdot\sqrt{2k}\frac{2k}{2k-1}\cdot\frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k)!!} \\
&=& \pi\sqrt{\frac{2k}{2k+1}}\frac{2k}{2k-1}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{(2k-1)!!^2(2k+1)}{(2k)!!^2}} \\ 
&=& \;\pi\sqrt{\frac{2k}{2k+1}}\frac{2k}{2k-1}\sqrt{\prod_{j=1}^{k}\frac{(2j-1)}{(2j)}\frac{(2j+1)}{(2j)}} \\ 
& \rightarrow & \pi\cdot\sqrt{1}\cdot1\sqrt{\prod_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2i-1)}{(2i)}\frac{(2i+1)}{(2i)}} \\ 
&=&\pi\cdot\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \\ 
&=& \sqrt{2\pi},\;k\rightarrow \infty
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Does this work if $n$ is odd?

Comment: Indeed it does. We actually get nice things to work with since the expression simplifies to $$2^{2n}\sqrt{2n+1}\frac{\Gamma(n)\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(2n+1)}$$

Comment: Thats cool! by the way in your above comment you should replace $n$ by $k$ so that you handle the $n = 2k + 1$ case. case $n = 2k$ is already handled in your answer. I wish i could upvote one more time!

Comment: It took a little bit of hacking but I got the equations to align nicely. Please in the future DO NOT write your answers the way you did initially. It was like Where's Waldo met Jackson Pollock.

Answer (score 4):

If we write

$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^n x \cos^{n-2} x\,dx = \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^{-2} x \exp\Bigl[n\log(\sin x \cos x)\Bigr]\,dx
$$

and note that the quantity $\log(\sin x \cos x)$ achieves a maximum over the interval of integration at $x = \pi/4$, then by calculating

$$
\log(\sin x \cos x) = -\log 2 - 2 \left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^2 + O\left(\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^4\right)
$$

and

$$
\cos^{-2} x = 2 + O\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)
$$

as $x \to \pi/4$ we may appeal to the Laplace method to conclude that

$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^n x \cos^{n-2} x\,dx \sim \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 2 e^{-n\log 2-2ny^2}\,dy = \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2^n\sqrt{n}}
$$

as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Just a fun little solution, because it should always be possible to solve these kinds of limits with one magic $u$-substitution. Consider under the interchange $x\leftrightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}-x$ we have

$$I_n \equiv \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}2^n\sqrt{n}\sin^{n}(x)\cos^{n-2}(x)dx = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}2^n\sqrt{n}\sin^{n-2}(x)\cos^{n}(x)dx$$

by symmetry which means equivalently we have that

$$I_n+I_n = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}2^n\sqrt{n}\sin^{n-2}(x)\cos^{n-2}(x)\Bigr(\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)\Bigr)dx $$

$$ \implies I_n = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}2^{n-1}\sqrt{n}\sin^{n-2}(x)\cos^{n-2}(x)dx = \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}2\sqrt{n}\sin^{n-2}(2x)dx$$

Then use the substitution $u = \sqrt{n-2}\left(x-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}2\sqrt{n}\sin^{n-2}(2x)dx = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{\frac{n}{n-2}}\int_{-\frac{\pi\sqrt{n-2}}{4}}^{\frac{\pi\sqrt{n-2}}{4}}2\cos^{n-2}\left(\frac{2u}{\sqrt{n-2}}\right)du$$

$$= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{\frac{n}{n-2}}\int_{-\frac{\pi\sqrt{n-2}}{4}}^{\frac{\pi\sqrt{n-2}}{4}}2\left(1-\frac{2u^2}{n-2}+\cdots\right)^{n-2}du \longrightarrow 1\cdot\int_{-\infty}^\infty2e^{-2u^2}du = \boxed{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$